# Why actually the fall through happens

Tags: java

I have searched this particular question a lot but didn't find any appropriate answers for it. Everywhere it's only written just only about when fall through happens , they haven't described my issue. Can anyone pls help me .

As we all know that switch case  goes to fall through condition if there is no break statement. But i wanna ask that if switch case check value by cases then , if suppose it is checking the second case and there is no break in the second case , then according to language protocols it must falls through but as switch checks and compare the cases then why shouldn't the compiler again checks the next case , i mean then why it runs the block of next case without checking the case equality.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Comment: That's just the way the `case` statement works...the way it was designed.  "dropping through" does not involve the second conditional expression.

Comment: [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) is *magical*. Also, it can be used to implement co-routines. But both are really side-effects of the way the `switch` statement is **implemented** by the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question is pretty interesting.

Comparison for equality is done only once, until the execution flow enters a case.
A break is not necessary because it allows to control the execution flow.
There are a lot of situations with switch/case when you'd like to execute case B and after that you'd like to execute all following cases (case C, case D, etc).
So, this limitation is by design.
Actually it's not a limitation.
It gives you some flexibility in using this statement.